# Why is the greatest Vaishnava a Tamasic entity per Vaishnavites?

Tags: shiva, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, gunas, jiva

there is a famous verse in Srimad Bhagavatam, a "satvika" purana, that says

> Just as Ganga among rivers, Achyuta among gods, Shambu among Vaishnavas, This (Bhagavatam) is the same among Puranas.

This obviously means Shambu(Siva) is the greatest Vishnu-devotee, exceeding all other beings such as "nitya suris", humans, devas and so forth.

But there is enormous Vaishnavite literature putting Siva down as a "Tamasic" entity and a mere Jiva subject to Karma and death.

Does Bhagavatam or any other Vaishnavite scripture reconcile these two viewpoints?

Comment: There is more to it. A prapanna (initiated into SVism) can't denigrate fellow Vaishnavas; he lose the inevitability of Moksha in case he denigrates any fellow Vaishnava...

Comment: Can you list some of the quotes from the "enormous vaishnavite literature putting Siva down"? Atleast one for each - 1) He is Tamasic. 2) He is a Jiva. 3) He is subject to karma & death. That would really help. Thank you.

Comment: can you give scriptural reference for - *exceeding all other beings such as "nitya suris"*. It is my belief that the verse is meant for jiva-atmas (excludes nitya suris and mukta atmas - because there is no comparison of 'greater' or 'lesser' bhakti once vaikunta is reached because of sayujya). Not Shiva alone, Brahma is also a Jivatma. Indra, Agni, all devas are considered Jivas, subject to karma, because those are posts, and people rotate into those posts based on their punya. Guna is not a barrier for Bhakti. There is satvik bhakti, rajas bhakti, tamas bhakti.

Comment: Ghantakarna had tamas bhakti, yet we extol him. Sudama had satvik bhakti, we extol him as well. The type of bhakti doesn't matter if the emotion is 100%. There are numerous verses that say *my devotees, irrespective of birth/guna, are the same to me. similarly, non devotees, irrespective of birth/guna, are the same to me*. You also need to differentiate between respecting someone and being attached to them. Vaishnavas are ordered never to disrespect/denigrate any other vaishnava, the punishment being moksha denied.

Comment: Lord Siva is not tamasic, he rules the entity falling in tamasic guna, by nature all Godly beings are sattvik that is why they are given divine work by God himself.. there is abhmanya devatha for every guna, for tamasic Siva and Durga here one had to note both the forms are for destruction, Durga takes precedence over Siva because of tartamya, Durga is another form of Lakshmi..

Comment: I don't think Vaishnavas say Shiva is tamsic. They believe Shiva controls the tama guna. Also Vaishnavas (like Gaudiya) believe Shiva to be almost identical to Vishnu( giving milk to curd example).  The only difference, accoding to them, is how Shiva takes part in material nature where Vishnu Himself remain untouched by it even though being Preserver. Personally, I believe both to be same even though I am closer to Vaishnavism.

Comment: Without referring to any scripture, my inference of Trinity - Brahma , Vishnu and Shiva, represent Tamas, Rajas and Satva respectively.  For any creation, (Brahma) one should undergo Tamas or passion. For ruling anything one should have the killing instinct or Rajas or I only can do it feeling (Vishnu).  For enlightenment or salvation , one needs Satvik character (Shiva).  So Shiva is not Tamasic, but in fact our Satvik

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, Rajas is creation/passion, Tamas is destruction/sleep, Satvik is preservation/equanimity. Shiva is the one who destroys, Brahma is the one who creates, Vishnu is the one who preserves. You have it mixed up.

Comment: *"There is no loophole to exclude Garuda, Sesha"* - that's your personal opinion/interpretation. The concept of Bhagavata, or any comparison between them, is only valid in Lila Vihbuti. Once you're Mukta atma, all are same. And they can't be compared with those in Lila Vibhuti because comparison can only make sense between apples, not apples and oranges.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, and a poster who has *really* understood the *depths* of Hinduism struggles to maintain a decorum of decency in his language.. the irony is strong as iron.

Comment: Why are you 2 users (SK, ram) making me a medium to make a comment on the other :-)?

Comment: I had understood your proposal and I will try to do that.  Though I myself have been at receiving end of derogatory remarks from some of the members in this site, yet I am continuing in this site, as every now and then, I am learning something new. @SK

Comment: @srimannarayana k v you an asset to he community.  My only suggestion is - just because it is about religion, you don't have to be too pious - some humor isn't out of place :-)

Comment: I am not good at this arguments.  Anyways, my inference had been drawn based on my observation.  Creation requires a passion - procreation involves passion.  So the Guna involved is Tamas . Preservation involves Rajas, as kshatriya rules a land, Vishnu rules the world.  So it involves Rajas only.  Finally, Shiva is involved not in destruction but merger in the ULTIMATE, which is nothing but Satva

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, passion is the mode of Rajas, not Tamas. you have it mixed up.

Comment: @ram Avoid personal attacks and unfriendly language. Read [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct). If you find something problematic (rude or offensive) then just flag it, don't start or get involved in unhealthy discussions.